# sqlite3 programming got "out of memory" in Linux C

Tags: c, database, linux, sqlite

My code is very simple, just create a empty table. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sqlite3 *ppdb;
    int retval;

    retval = sqlite3_open_v2("v2.db", &ppdb, 
                        SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, "unix-none");
    if (retval != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        printf(stderr, "%s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(ppdb));
        return 1;
    }
    retval = sqlite3_exec(ppdb, 
             "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userinfo \
             (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, pass TEXT NOT NULL)",
             NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (retval != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(ppdb));
        return 1;
    }
    sqlite3_close(ppdb);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run it, I got this error message:

`Out of memory`

I debug this code, I found `sqlite3_open_v2` has returned `21`(Library used incorrectly)

How to solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html):

> The `flags` parameter to `sqlite3_open_v2()` can take one of the following three values, [...]:
>
> `SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY`
>   The database is opened in read-only mode. If the database does not already exist, an error is returned.
>
> `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE`
>   The database is opened for reading and writing if possible, or reading only if the file is write protected by the operating system. In either case the database must already exist, otherwise an error is returned.
>
> `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE`
>   The database is opened for reading and writing, and is created if it does not already exist. This is the behavior that is always used for `sqlite3_open()` and `sqlite3_open16()`.

So you can't use just `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE`, you need to include the `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` bit if you want it to create the file:

```
retval = sqlite3_open_v2("v2.db", &ppdb,
                    SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, "unix-none");
```